# How can i customize answer of Bot Framework Help Command?

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I use Bot Framework form flow for a Turkish Bot. I want to change help command's answer to turkish. Is there any options for this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Template attribute on top of your Form definition to override the Help string pattern. The pattern is located in the Resources.resx of Microsoft.Bot.Builder project.

```
[Template(TemplateUsage.Help, new string[] { "My custom Help message" })]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, there is no explain in bot framework documentations

Answer (score 0):

I think the following articles give you some information about how to localize your content by language. [Bot Framework Localize content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize) and [localization in Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160128/is-that-possible-to-develop-localization-in-microsoft-bot-framework-using-c)

Hope it will help to someone.