# Is that possible to develop localization in Microsoft Bot framework using C#?

Tags: c#, botframework

I want a bot that supports multiple languages. I know that it is possible through localization. But I can't find a solution for using c#.
There is an article regarding localization in Microsoft Bot framework docs.
There is example with node.js. But I am implementing in c#. So, can anyone give me an idea or any reference through which I'll be able to implement localization in c#?

Answer (score 0):

The FormFlow Improved Sandwich Bot has some C# BotFramework localization documentation.  It can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize

> The localization language is determined by the current thread's
>   CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture. By default the culture comes from
>   the Language field of the current message, but you can change that if
>   you wish. Depending on your bot, there can be up to 3 different
>   sources of localized information including: The built-in localization
>   for PromptDialog and FormFlow. A resource file generated from the
>   static strings found in your form. A resource file you create with
>   strings for dynamically computed fields, messages or confirmations.

This page also references IFormBuilder.SaveResource, the rview tool, as well as the Multilingual App Toolkit.  These can all help make bot localization easier.

Comment: I used the Rview tool to generate the resource file for the Formflow, but left the MAT for what it is and used the more handy VS extension called ResXmanager to translate the resource strings.

Comment: @pursang. Can you help me how to use Rview Tool. I am using form flow and want to localise all the strings in it.

Comment: @EhsanUlHaq Please ask a new question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've been able to hard set the locale for all dialogs by setting the activity.Locale in the MessagesController. This effectively overrides the current (UI) culture of all threads used for dialogs. I first tried setting the current (UI) culture dialog per dialog, but this is highly unefficient (also, the locale of the activity sometimes takes over).

Answer (score 0):

To completely localize your bot, you need to consider the texts in

- Form Flow
- Prompt dialog
- Normal messages to user

Form flow localization documentation can be found at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize.

For prompt dialog and normal messages, create a Resources.resx file for your default language. From there you can create another resx for other languages such as Resources.fr.resx for french. Consider using [MAT Tool](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit) for generating Resources.fr.resx. Then change your code to point to these **resource file texts** instead of hard coded text. Take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers#localization . It has the sample which shows exactly what I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

in your Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization();
}
```

in your bot class:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    BotResource.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); 
    //OR 
    BotResource.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo(turnContext.Activity.Locale); 
}
```